# SVG animate only with "to" attribute

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I want to animate an SVG path to 2 different states. For this, I've created a triangle path, with 2 example animations, which I trigger through Javascript.

These animations only have the "to" attribute because the intention is to animate the path from whatever state is in to any other desired state (the final animation will have 10+ states).

You can see a working example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dxvlt

The problem is that, at least in Chrome, if you click Animation1, then Animation2, then back to Animation1 it works fine. However, right after that, animations stop working, or only one of them works. I believe the animation is triggered, but it's not being drawn. This problem does not happen in Firefox, and I've read that Webkit and Blink have numerous SVG bugs.

Do you know a workaround to make it draw correctly on Chrome as well?

Comment: Animation in svg is a bit of a fiddly beast, especially when it comes to things like fill and to, and its quite hard to get things consistent. I think it can be fine for animation sequences, but less so for more interactive stuff (and what if someone clicks mid animation etc). I personally would code a solution using one of the animation libs out there, or maybe a solution manually adjusting the attributes of the element and doing your own animation if that makes sense

Comment: Please file a bug at http://crbug.com.